# Validating form field in Angular with regEx

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-forms

I'm following the [official angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) , but it's not working for me. What could be wrong ? I need to validate if the mobile phone are required and following the international standard like +4400000000 (plus signal and numbers, no space, only numbers after the plus).

My code is....

```
.controller('ModalInstanceChangeDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope,  $uibModalInstance, items) {
    $scope.rxMobile = '^\+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3,14}$';
}

<form name="form">
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Mobile number</label><label class="fieldError" ng-show="form.mobile.$error.required || !form.mobile.$valid">This field is required and must use International format, ex: +440000000000</label>
        <input ng-pattern="rxMobile" required ng-model="mobile" name="mobile" type="text" class="form-control">
 </div>
</form>
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

use this *regex* to validate international standard phone number :

`$scope.rxMobile = '^\\+\\d{10}\\b';`

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^^+d{10}$/: Nothing to repeat
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>) --- $scope.rxMobile= "^\+\d{10}\b";

Comment: @MarcoJr check edit

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex to validate the phone number

> +[\d]{10}$

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what's wrong...

```
 $scope.rxMobile = /^\+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3,14}$/;
```

It's works if I enclose it without quotation.